# Java Integer to Binary confusion

Tags: java, bit

According to my comprehension, `Integer` type in `Java` is 32-bit-signed, the most significant bit is the signed bit. This is why `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`, which is:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111(1 repeated in 31 times).
```

So I assume that it actually can be represented as:

```
01111111111111111111111111111111(a 0 followed by 1 repeated 31 times)
```

The `0` means this is a positive integer.

Then for the following codes:

```
    int test = -2147483647;
    String converted = Integer.toBinaryString(test);
    System.out.println(converted);
```

The output is:

```
 10000000000000000000000000000001
```

Why the output is like above? For me, the binary stream should be represented as `-1`, since the most significant bit is `1` means negative.

Like this:

```
    int minusOne = -1;
    String converted1 = Integer.toBinaryString(test);
    System.out.println(converted1);
```

The output is the same as above:

```
10000000000000000000000000000001
```

Any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the folowing two snippets, did you find the problem:

```
int test = -2147483647;
String converted = Integer.toBinaryString(test);
System.out.println(converted);

int minusOne = -1;
String converted1 = Integer.toBinaryString(test);
System.out.println(converted1);
```

You are printing out the same variable test, that's why the output is the same. If you printout "minusOne" it would be all 1's.

```
10000000000000000000000000000001 -> -2147483647 = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1
11111111111111111111111111111111 -> -1

1111111111111111111111111111111  -> Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
10000000000000000000000000000000 -> Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1
10000000000000000000000000000000 -> Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648
10000000000000000000000000000001 -> Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @dragon66's point, be aware that these are [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) numbers. They are not represented as sign, magnitude.

In two's complement representation, one negates a number by inverting all the bits, then adding 1. This way, there's only one representation of 0.